# Migrate time in mongoDB from localtime to UTC

Tags: javascript, mongodb, time

In MongoDB I store a time in epoch seconds, that is a local time for Berlin. I'd like to migrate that time to a more appropriate way and convert it to UTC time.

The thing is I need to preserve the Summer/Winter time difference for all records so I can not specify the offcet.

The problem is, in MongoDB script I can not create the `Date` object in Berlin timezone.

The commands like:

`new Date('Aug 08, 2021 00:00:00 (Europe/Berlin)').toISOString()`

or

`new Date(1630281600000).toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: "Europe/Berlin" })` 
ignores timezone, and converts the time to my local timezone.

I've googled a lot about additional libraries, but I can not install anything so it's not an option for me

Comment: Did you try with moment-timezone ?

Comment: moment is an additional library, but unfortunately I can not install any

Comment: moment.js is a single Javascript file (or maybe two files if you need time zones) Simply download it and store it on your machine at any path. Load it in your Mongo shell script with `load("the_path/moment.js")` or in worst case copy-paste the code directly.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit the thing is it's not my local pc, it's the remote prod server, so I do not have access to download anything

Comment: Download the file to your local PC -> open the file with a text editor ->Copy all -> paste code in your mongo shell (or put it on top of your mongo script).