# Date in MongoDB does not take timezone into account

Tags: javascript, mongodb, time

I have UTC time, that I want to convert to a time within a specific timezone, so I wrote the function:

`new Date('Aug 08, 2021 00:00:00 (Europe/Berlin)').toISOString()`

I get `2021-08-07T21:00:00.000Z` but that seems true for my local timezone, not for the specific one.
Meanwhile the correct time is `2021-08-07T22:00:00.000Z` what is an hour more.

Why this one is not working?

Comment: mongo stores dates in UTC format

Comment: @dododo can you please explain? I take the time as UTC and by putting timezone, I'm saying mongo to assume that's Europe/Berlin time. If it does not work that way - why there is a possibility to specify a timezone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrate time in mongoDB from localtime to UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68759215/migrate-time-in-mongodb-from-localtime-to-utc)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I guess that solves the problem, but does not answer my question ;-)

Comment: I don't think the time zone enclosed by brackets is according to any standard. Again, use moment.js library, there you can specify the input format.